# Which is more efficient PreparedStatementSetter and PreparedStatementCreator in Spring?

Tags: java, database, spring, jsp, frameworks

I was wondering during development

Which is more efficient PreparedStatementSetter(Object) and PreparedStatementCreator(Object) and safe in spring framework?

Comment: I doubt very much that you'd be able to tell the difference. Performance will entirely be governed by the communication with the database, and the access plan performance. Use whichever is more *convenient*. Beware premature optimization.

Comment: Internally always a `PreparedStatement` is going to be used. You don't need to do it yourself, unless you are writing some complex queries which require additional logic. Else just use the `query(String, ...)` methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use both in conjunction. PreparedStatementCreator to create a PreparedStatement object. Then PreparedStatementSetter to set the parameter values.

```
String machaceksName = (String) jdbcTemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
  public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    return connection
        .prepareStatement("select first_name from customer where last_name like ?");
  }
}, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
  public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
    preparedStatement.setString(1, "Mach%");
  }
}, new ResultSetExtractor() {
  public Object extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
    if (resultSet.next()) {
      return resultSet.getLong(1);
    }
    return null;
  }
});
```

I would prefer to pass a Prepared Statement SQL query and use of PreparedStatementSetter to set the parameter values as it will minimize the time/memory spend to create PreparedStatementCreator.

```
 int r = jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_INSERT, new PreparedStatementSetter() {};
```